# How to handle RS-232 grounding when connecting multiple devices?

Tags: rs232

I need to connect multiple devices using RS232 in a ring where the TX of one device goes into the RX of the next device. I will use a copper cable for the physical layer.

I can't use RS485 that supports multidrop instead.

I don't know how to handle grounding.

I don't know if I need some other components (comm boards, etc..)

Comment: If all devices are close each to other you can connect all grounds in a single point. The devices have to be supplied with a galvanic isolation between mains.

Comment: This is a strange configuration.. in the case of 3 devices the connection would be : Tx1->Rx2 , Tx2->Rx3, Tx3->Rx1 ? Meaning that if Device 1 says "hello" to Device 2, for device 2 to reply he would need to tell device 3 to tell device 1 "hello" ?

Grounding would be all grounds together, I would suggest avoiding a loop meaning : Gnd1 --  Gnd2 -- Gnd3  but do not connect again Gnd3 to Gnd 1